# Where to put savechanges in unit of work pattern with asp.net mvc?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, razor-2

I am using a generic repository pattern in asp.net mvc. I am familiar with repository pattern but not with Unit of work. I am reading several articles from google about this. But I am not sure if I use unit of work with asp.net mvc, where would I use Commit() method that will call the ef SaveChanges() method? Will I use it on repository layer or service layer or in Controller. Also, many others are saying that, Microsoft is already using Unit Of work built in with Entity Framework. So no need to use it separately or use it controller level or anywhere?

Thanks,
Abdus Salam Azad.

Comment: I am voting to close this as there are already dozens of SO threads on that with different opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you have to do it inside the `UnitOfWork.cs` class.

**UnitOfWork.cs**

```
 public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
   {

       private DbContext _dbContext;

       public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
       {         
          _dbContext = context;
       }

       public int Commit()
       {
           return _dbContext.SaveChanges();// Save changes 
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
           Dispose(true);
           GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
       }

      private void Dispose(bool disposing)
       {
           if (disposing)
           {
               if (_dbContext != null)
               {
                   _dbContext.Dispose();
                   _dbContext = null;
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

After that you can call UnitOfWork's `Commit` method inside the **Service Layer**.

**EntityService.cs**

```
public abstract class EntityService<T> : IEntityService<T> where T : BaseEntity
   {
       IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
       IGenericRepository<T> _repository;

       public EntityService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IGenericRepository<T> repository)
       {
           _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
           _repository = repository;
       }  

     public virtual void Create(T entity)
           {
               _repository.Add(entity);
               _unitOfWork.Commit(); //saving point        
           }

}
```

You can learn more about this pattern : [**Generic Repository and Unit of Work Pattern**](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: What if you want to make multiple changes and save all the modifications at the end? How would you handle that? I'm in this situation and I cannot find a proper way to do the save method

Comment: @IonutEnache You need to use `Transactions` then: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple operation on a same transaction. Then after finishing all your operation, you will need to put your savechanges() finally. If it succeeded, all operation will be succeeded and if failed, all operations will be failed and reverted.

```
            _employeeService.UpdateVehicleDetail(model);
            _employeeService.UpdateLicenseDetail(model);
            await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```